# How to Render Form in Angular2 asking for better logic?

Tags: angular, logic

I am rendering form through Rest API.What I want to get the following things.

1. First get the form Object in which I have form fields array in which I need to collect all parents says in `parent_array`.
2. Then In the second step, I have to compare the parent with form fields array to get all those(field a property in form json) whose parent is same.
3. I need to create a Data Structure object for that.Syntax like this.
   `FormSet={parent:value,children:[]}`.I need children as an array to put all field in this based on the comparison in step 2.

Question what is the best way to do this in angular 2.

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly you want to achieve ?

Comment: I want to render back-end form through Rest API.I have available json how do I render that ?

Comment: You need to get the whole object as Json, and subscriber pushes data results into "results" object. You can use  angular directives to read the data from results object. 

 this.result = http.get('your.json')
                  .map(response => response.json())
                  .subscribe(result => this.result =result.json());

Comment: I done this.I am asking about next three step which I asked in above post.